# Passing Page ID to the DCP

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and in the need to pass Page TCM URI to a Dynamic Component Presentation (not embedded on the page).
I am following [THIS](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/passing_the_pageURI_to_a_DCP_for_dynamic_linking.aspx) link from Mihai (which I guess is for Tridion 2011) and wondering if this applied to Tridion 2013 SP1 as well.

If it does, the main issue I am getting is locating the below file mentioned in article - `Tridion.Extensions.ContentDelivery.Utility.dll` - can someone suggest where can I get this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Google to the rescue: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/Bin/ EDIT: download doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Yeah thanks...tried that, but none of the location allows to copy or download

Comment: I seriously doubt that file on World is the one you need, that would be the 2009 version, which maybe actually is the version of SDL Tridion that Mihai is talking about in that article ;). Its a shame he wrote this as an article without a download, seems we are missing something (I think the files which @AlbertRomkes located via Google are protected by IIS because they belong to the web application, so should never really have been indexed)

Comment: have you looked at http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/04/passing-pageuri-to-dcp-for-dynamic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got connected to the blog author and got a confirmation that the `Tridion.Extensions.ContentDelivery.Utility.dll` is not a Tridion product but a custom DLL written for this specific purpose.

To pass the Page URI to the DCP on the CD side I used below code - Thanks for the help Nick :):

```
ComponentLink compLink = new ComponentLink(publicationID);
Link pageLink = compLink.GetLink(currentPageTCMURI, currentComponentTCMURI, currentCTTCMURI, null, null, null, null);
var detailsPageUri = pageLink.TargetUri;
```

I hope this will help someone else.